# Running a background Method in Cache

Tags: intersystems-cache

I have a classmethod in a class that I want to execute in a background process:

```
ClassMethod Test()
{}
```

Which I execute in this way:

```
JOB ##(MyClass).Test()
```

..assuming that 'Test' is defined in MyClass.

However, I get an exception that METHOD DOES NOT EXIST, but everything works well when I use `do ##(MyClass).Test()`

I am fairly new to cache, so I cannot explain why this is happening. The task I am running is a long running one and I cannot affort to have it run on the same process.

Comment: do not forget to compile after save

Answer (score 0):

it should work. Are you in the right namespace?